# Deleted Foreign Key Constraint causing error

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a FK constraint by using this auto created script.

```
USE [PRM.Mobile.SaaS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Activity] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Activity_Activity] 
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentActivityID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Activity] ([ActivityID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Activity] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Activity_Activity]
GO
```

But I get these errors:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_Activity_Activity". The conflict occurred in database "PRM.Mobile.SaaS", table "dbo.Activity", column 'ActivityID'.
>
> Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 8
>   Constraint 'FK_Activity_Activity' does not exist.
>
> Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 8
>   Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.

Looks pretty straightforward but I don't have any FK with a name of `FK_Activity_Activity` anymore. Also first message being a FK constraint preventing the action and second message being that constraint is not existing is a bit confusing.

I double checked the `INFORMATION.SCHEMA` and `sys.objects` and nothing with a name of `FK_Activity_Activity` shows up.

These are the queries I used for checking

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%Activity_Activity%'
```

and

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ConstraintName,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
    type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM 
    sys.objects
WHERE 
    type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' 
    AND OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 'Activity'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Has the table another foreign keys ?

Answer (score 0):

The `add constraint` failed with the first error: the FK is not created.

The second error is from the second statement because the FK does not exist.

Everything else follows from there.

R TABLE [dbo].[Activity] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Activity_Activity] 
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentActivityID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Activity] ([ActivityID])

To fix things so you can create the index you need to correct your data so it is consistent with the new FK *before* you create the index. Whether than is modifying the data in `ParentActivityID` or `ActivityID` only you can say.

But note any recursive structure needs to allow for `ParentActivityID` being null (unless the graph is specifically cyclic). Usually this is by making it null.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that but still how can I create this FK ?

Comment: @EgeBayrak, to create the foreign key constraint, you'll either need to first fix the existing problem data or specify the `NOCHECK` option when creating the foreign key. Existing data will violate the constraint in the later case but new rows will be validated.